# Matching and Placing Values from Another Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to develop a check box switch on a form that auto-fills a check mark when the correct value is selected.

| Item | Group | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Keyboard | Medium | Electronics |
| Laptop | High | Electronics |
| Mouse Pad | Low | Electronics |
| Apple | Low | Food |
| Wine | High | Food |
| Milk | Medium | Food |

**Goal:**
I have a listbox that allows multiple selection of items, given a certain criteria "Category". The list automatically updates based on the category selected. Once selected, I want to see if the item selected falls under a certain "Group", either low, medium, or high.

**Current Code:**

```vb
' Create Array for multiple selection box
Dim ct As Integer, v, ArrCT()
ReDim ArrCT(ct = 0 To Me.testbutton.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)

For Each v In Me.testbutton.ItemsSelected
    ArrCT(ct) = Me.testbutton.ItemData(v)
    ct = 1 + ct
Next v

' Load table for matching
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MasterList")

Dim qmct As Integer, x, NewArr()
ReDim NewArr(qmct = 0 to Me.testbutton.ItemsSelected.Count - 1)

For Each x In Me.testbutton.ItemsSelected
    NewArr(qmct) = ArrCT(x)
        If NewArr(qmct) = rs![Item] Then
            NewArr(qmct) = rs![Group]
        End If
    qmct = 1 + qmct
Next x
```

My idea was to create a temporary array which stores the selection, and then have a second for-loop go through the array to match the correct "group".

With the second array, despite triple checking the field name, I get:

> Run-time error '3265':
> Item not found in this collection.

Item information is loaded in the ArrCT array, and adjusts based on the number of selection.

Is there an easier way to call for a value in the table?

*Note: sample table is not my actual data, that has approximately 20 times more items, category and grouping.

Comment: It is preferred that data be included as a text table, not image. Easiest approach is to include the Group field as a column in listbox RowSource. Reference that column by its index when looping listbox selection. What do you want to happen once the Group value is determined?

Comment: Should include in your question the exact message of the 3265 error.

Comment: I believe in the original file, the rowsource is modified so it's a sql query with the three columns listed in it. 

Ultimately the form is supposed to do a final validation to see if the correct information is inputted. For example, there's a couple of more selection criteria in the list prior to this list box, changing the requirements based on the combination. This step "attaching the group value" is supposed to not only create a check box flag (for visual notification) but also used later on for validation.

Comment: Does not alter my original recommendation. Is the posted sample data from the "MasterList"? Could delete the image.

Comment: I currently only have one of the column that I want them selecting showing, since I don't want the other users to be confused with the multiple rows (but all three are included).

I'm a bit confused in regards to the column index, would Access generate a unique index for each selection possible, or would it change based on the current selections? If the list shown is restricted, would it default to 0, 1, 2 based on what's shown, or is the listindex consistent to the original table order? So if I have 60 rows in total does it go up to 60 by default, or does it change based on the restriction?

Comment: Number of rows in list has nothing to do with column index. Index is 0 based. If field is in second column its index is 1. So refer to that column index: `Me.testbutton.Column(1)`. When looping through a listbox Selection: `Me.testbutton.Column(1, x)`. Columns don't have to be visible. Your code just isn't making sense to me. Exactly what are you trying to 'match'?